# Image saving into database from a folder and get back into the UI

Tags: c#, webforms

I have a field in my app (c#) to save an image into the database. I written the following code to save the image into a folder and then save the path into the database. But the image is not getting saved into the folder.

```
string imgName = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
        string imgPath = null;
        if (imgName == "")
        {
            //int taxiid = Convert.ToInt32(HiddenField1.Value);
            Taxi t = null;
            t = Taxi.Owner_GetByID(tx.Taxi_Id, USM.OrgId);
            imgPath = t.CarImage;
        }
        else
        {
            imgPath = "ImageStorage/" + imgName;
        }
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
        tx.CarImage = imgPath;
```

Comment: put your code inside Try{} catch(){} block for exact error.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a web app? How are you posting your image to the server? Is it ASP.NET Web Forms or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: It is ASP.NET Web Form

Comment: do you get any error? And what is in imgPath?

Comment: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\indian\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TMS_Ntiers_D\TMS_Ntiers\TaxiCompany\ImageStorage\Chrysanthemum.jpg'. This is the error that I'm getting

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you add the name to the Path I try it and for me it works fine if I save it like this:

> FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("ImageStorage") + imgName);

And as @Rahul mentioned add a try catch to prevent errors.

And you check

> if (imgName == "")

According to my understanding it's not posible that imgName is "" but anyway you better add a check if the fileupload has a file.

> if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)

Comment: the image got saved with the path in the database but it is not got saved in the folder ImageStorage in my project after using FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("ImageStorage") + imgName);

Comment: how to set the size of the image